# Is there a way in JavaScript to handle errors by the error name?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am still learning JavaScript. I know Python too and in Python we can handle specific errors, for example to handle `TypeErrors` in Python, we could simply use `except TypeError:` and handle it. I want to know if there is a way in JavaScript to handle errors like,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

in this way. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a syntax error, that means that your code is invalid. I'm not sure how you want to handle that.

Comment: You can catch runtime errors, and it'll usually be pretty obvious from the context which error it's going to be. Your approach seems to only make sense in the context of providing users a platform where they can run their own code.

Comment: @VLAZ, I am working of a calculator with JS. This error occurred after I entered a number with 2 decimals, `1.2.4`.

Comment: @Poornaka `eval` is a poor way of getting calculator functionality. The syntax errors are one of the issues. You  might also hit *valid* syntax that's not valid mathematical expression. So, it "works" (doesn't throw error) when it probably should. But it doesn't "work" because you get an unexpected result out of it.  `5 +-+-+-+ 4` is `1` but `5 +--+-+ 4` is a syntax error. `5.` is a valid number but `5..` is not.

Comment: Can you please suggest another way instead of `eval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try...catch method

```js
try {
  // your code
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err.name)
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

There are several types of error in JavaSript like: RangeError, ReferenceError, SyntaxError, TypeError, URIError
So you can check for particular error type with `err.name` property like this

```
if (err.name === 'SyntaxError') {
            //handle that error type
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the point of my question. I want to handle specific errors. That means I don't want to handle every error. I want to handle it only if it is, for example, a `syntax error`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an javascript expert but I handled my errors so far like:

```
try {
  foo.bar();
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof ErrorType) {
    console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
  }
  // ... etc
}
```

where `ErrorType` is a placeholder in my example.

**Edit:**
As @VLAZ stated, this will only work for Runtime-Errors.